# iOS managing nested UICollectionViews issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I've encountered a problem while dealing with nested collection views.
Hierarchy is as follows:

- outerCollectionView

  - UIImageView
  - Label
  - innerCollectionView

    - Label
    - UIImageView

OuterCollectionView's cells are of the size of the screen (works like swiping through pages)
I've set outerCollectionView's delegate and datasource to be UIViewController and innerCollectionView's delegate and datasource to be the containing cell as follows:

- in the ViewController.m

  ```
  -(FeaturedPageCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  FeaturedPageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FeaturedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.nestedCollectionView.dataSource = cell;
  cell.nestedCollectionView.delegate = cell;
  [cell.nestedCollectionView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.01]];
  cell.venueThumbnail.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.venueThumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
  cell.venueNameLabel.text = [self.venueNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
  cell.venueNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  cell.venueAddressLabel.text = [self.venueAddresses objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
  cell.venueAddressLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [cell setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor grayColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:.1]];
  return cell;
  }
  ```
- in implementation file for the cell that contains innerCollectionView

  ```
  -(FeaturedEventCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  FeaturedEventCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FeaturedEventCellReuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.eventDateLabel.text = [self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
  cell.eventDateLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  cell.eventImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Flyer%ld.png", self.venueNameLabel.text, (long)indexPath.item +1]];
  return cell;
  }
  ```

  In this block of code I am using value of containing cell's label to load relevant to that cell data into innerCollectionView.

Pretty straight forward implementation. The result is not what I expected at all. Basically what's happening is that data gets loaded properly into cells of outerCollectionView, but not into the cells of innerCollectionView ( the very first one get loaded correctly, but not the rest of them). Also scrolling through items in innerCollectionView will cause scrolling in the rest of the cells.

I thought that making the containing cell a delegate of innerCollectionView would manage it's own collection view independently from others. I think am not understanding something fundamental about collection views, dequeuing and reusing.

Also is nesting collection views a good way of implementing of my scenario? I tried to look up on implementing nested collection views and couldn't find a whole lot maybe for a reason?

Please, explain what I am doing wrong in my case or direct me towards correct or better solution.

Comment: I would expect to see you setting the cell's `events` property as part of your first method, but I can't see that anywhere. Where does it come from?

Comment: have you been able to fix this?