# Nesting UICollectionViews vs UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uipageviewcontroller

I found myself in the need to implement the following: scrolling through pages and displaying a tableview or collectionview with the data relevant only to that particular page in the lower part of the screen. First I tried to use nested UICollectionViews making the cell of the outer UICollectionView to be the size of the screen and setting inner UICollectionView's delegate to the containing cell (outer UICollectionView's cell). I ran into the issue of data not getting loaded properly into inner Collection view. The problem is better described in this question:[nesting UICollectionViews issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273796/ios-managing-nested-uicollectionviews-issue)

Anyway, I looked more into UIPageViewController as a possible solution to the problem. I have never implemented UIPageViewController before and not sure if this could be a good fit for my problem. If anybody has done something like that before, please direct me to the right place or resource.

I still would like to go with nested UICollectionViews if possible and I don't quite understand why it is working as desired. Once again my problem is described better in the link above. Please advise on both options.

Answer (score 0):

When using a UIPageViewController you have to implement the reusing mechanism by yourself, that is the only downside i can see. Basically i would prefer UIPageViewController cause it is cleaner then nested collectionViews.